# Need to Access Item Index in Bootstrap Vue Table when doing a loop

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

1. I have a Bootstrap-Vue parent b-table running for loop on bids. Each bid also has items.
   Initially it shows each bid on each row.
2. When that row is clicked it shows a child table that has every bid items.
   So a child table inside `<template slot="hidden-details>` tries to
   loop through `bid.items` to display those items for each bid.
   Since I am unable to get earlier bid loop indexes I cannot run this
   nested loop unless I manually set it like: `:items="bid[0].items`

#### Script

```
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data:{
           bids: [{
              id: "Bid Number One",
              item: [{
                  item_number: 11,
                  item_text: "Item 1 Comment 1",
                  code: "1",
                },
                {
                  item_number: 22,
                  item_text: "Item 1 Comment 2",
                  code: "2",
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: "Bid Number Two",
              item: [{
                  item_Number: 33,
                  item_text: "Item 2 Comment 3",
                  code: "3",
                },
                {
                  item_Number: 44,
                  item_text: "Item 2 Comment 4",
                  code: "4",
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
         bidHeaderFields:[
         {key:"id", label: "Header"},
                 ],
         bidIndex: 0,
        },

      methods: {
            showBidItems(bids, index) { // Here I receive row index from @row-clicked
              this.bids[index]._showDetails = !this.bids[index]._showDetails;
              this.bidIndex = index; // I change the value of bidIndex to row-clicked index
             
            
          },
         }
})
```

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhqL8xrt/3/) has the table code.

Comment: I think your code has disappeared in the process of asking your question. Please edit your question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

The complete row's item data is available in the scoped details slot.  If the bid details are a sub-array of the item, you can just pass that array to the child b-table:

```html
<b-table :items="bids" :fields="..." ... >
  <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="{ item }"> // item === 'bid' row data
    // item.item === the rows 'item' array
    <b-table :items="item.item" :fields="..."></b-table>
  </template>
</b-table>
```